# Static Blocks shown crazy in frontend

Tags: block-cache, ce-1.9.2.0

There are new problems with static blocks in 1.9.2

> there is one more problem with CMS blocks caching, that is not fixed.
>
> If you are using secure urls and {{media}} tags in your CMS blocks,
>   you will receive "Insecure content warning" message from browser, as
>   Magento serves insecure links from cache.
>
> To resolve it, you need to add one more cache info tag, as
>
> (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),

Does anyone know where to add this code-snippet?

KNOWN BUG: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870

Comment: I am not sure about that, but you can specify your media tags to get from secure. Read this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/magentos-secure-unsecure-image-link-link-securely-for-secure-pages-only

Comment: Why not ask this as a comment in the original answer? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70732/2190

Comment: Not able because of missing reputation.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Magento CMS Block will not be cached. So it would be nice if we cache CMS static blocks. This is what [***this extension does***](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache) (one of my free extension). Feel free to use it.

Basically this extension listens to the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and enable cacheing for CMS Blocks. This is what observer does

```
public function enableCmsBlockCaching(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Cms_Block_Widget_Block
        || $block instanceof Mage_Cms_Block_Block
    ) {

        $cacheKeyData = array(
            Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,
            $block->getBlockId(),
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            intval(Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure())
        );
        $block->setCacheKey(implode('_', $cacheKeyData));

        $block->setCacheTags(array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,
            (string)$block->getBlockId()
        ));

        $block->setCacheLifetime(false);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

***What this Observer Does*** : It first retrieve each static blocks from the layout and then apply cache. The unique `cache key` is generated for each static blocks. This unique key is made up of

- CMS cache tag
- Static Block Identifier
- Current Store Used
- Secure Url or Not

So the `cache key` will be unique in most of the circumstances and you already saw that for secure and not secure urls, cache key will be different. That's it.

Note : As @AdershKatri pointed out, you should also have look on ***[this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/magentos-secure-unsecure-image-link-link-securely-for-secure-pages-only)***

If you have any doubts, let me know.

Comment: I have tested this and it does resolve the problem, but will this result in Magento caching the static block data twice? Once by the (buggy) core code, and then again by your observer?

Comment: nope. as you can see, the extension is setting some values. Nothing more nothing less. Later magento will use this cache values to generate cache.. So no twice cacheing.

Comment: Ok, I understand that now, good solution. Can I suggest you add a modman installer for the module to your git project.

Comment: it would be greatly appreciated if you can make a pull request for that..

Comment: pull request done.

Answer (score 2):

`1.9.2` introduced caching to `cms/block` blocks, seen [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cb52550f2aa31026dfa9cb95709c567ebe3fded7/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php#L37-L50)

```
class Mage_Cms_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        /*
        * setting cache to save the cms block
        */
        $this->setCacheTags(array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG));
        $this->setCacheLifetime(false);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The edit you're quoting is suggesting to add the fact the request is secure to differentiate one cache from the other.  This means modifying/extending `Mage_Cms_Block_Block` using the `getCacheKeyInfo()` method with something like

```
class Mage_Cms_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    // ...
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        if ($this->getBlockId()) {
            return array(
                Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,
                Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
                $this->getBlockId(),
                (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
            );
        } else {
            return parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cms page content will get filter by following file.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
```

[Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::mediaDirective](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L285-L289)

You can make copy of the file and paste it in  local codepool and do you changes.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution while the bug is being fixed is to go system>cache management and tick the 'Blocks HTML output' and in actions 'disable'. You can enable when Magento has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in Magento 1.9.2.1 released 4th August 2015.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870