# Where to add (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),

Tags: cache

I facing issue described [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/ee-1-14-2-ce-1-9-2-block-caching-update-has-non-unique-cache-keys-duplicate)

I added the code to app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php at line 72:

and into

In `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Widget/Block.php` at line 82:

But someone also stated that:

```
(int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
```

Needs to be added in order to solve the issue completely, I just can't figure out in which file and where it needs to be added.

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my free extension does. That is it will cache magento static block by considering store, cms tag, block identifier, secure or not. ***[Please have a look](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache)*** or you can install it.

For more info, please have ***[look at here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/static-blocks-shown-crazy-in-frontend/73558#73558)***

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the original issue you need to add the isCurrentlySecure() call within the $result array of both changes.

app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php

```
             }
         return $html;
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Retrieve values of properties that unambiguously identify unique content
+     *
+     * @return array
+     */
+    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
+    {
+        $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
+        if ($blockId) {
+            $result = array(
+                $blockId,
+                Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(),
                 (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
+            );
+        } else {
+            $result = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
+        }
+        return $result;
+    }
 }
```

app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Widget/Block.php

```
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
                 $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
                 $this->setText($processor->filter($block->getContent()));
+                $this->addModelTags($block);
             }
         }

         unset(self::$_widgetUsageMap[$blockHash]);
         return $this;
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Retrieve values of properties that unambiguously identify unique content
+     *
+     * @return array
+     */
+    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
+    {
+        $result = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
+        $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
+        if ($blockId) {
+            $result[] = $blockId;
+            $result[] = (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure();
+        }
+        return $result;
+    }
 }
```

Comment: Don't you think that in app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php it should be: (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(), (with comma)?

Comment: @user20620 it's the last item in the array so it shouldn't require a comma

Comment: Thank you I am going to try and hope it won't give any error.